# How can I remove "grep: XXX: Is a directory" logs appearing when terminal is opened?

Tags: terminal, grep, zsh

How can I remove `grep: XXX: Is a directory` logs appearing when terminal is opened?

Why does these logs always appear?

```
Last login: Fri Jan 28 14:44:36 on ttys005
grep: Applications: Is a directory
grep: Desktop: Is a directory
grep: Documents: Is a directory
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
grep: Library: Is a directory
grep: Movies: Is a directory
grep: Music: Is a directory
grep: Pictures: Is a directory
grep: Postman: Is a directory
grep: Public: Is a directory
grep: Sites: Is a directory
grep: test: Is a directory
grep: work: Is a directory

~
❯
```

- zsh
- macOS Big Sur 11.6.2

Comment: Usually in Linux, there is a `-d` option along with which an action can be specified like skip, etc. Like `grep -d skip ...`

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you for your comment! Before I type any command, `grep: XXX: Is a directory` appears. 
`grep -d skip ...` is the command to use for each action? 
I'd like to not show `grep: XXX: Is a directory` globally when I open terminal.

Comment: I meant, `grep -d skip "text_to_search" *`. `-d skip` means skip all directories. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html

Comment: @kiner_shah I see. This command can be used to exclude all directories from the search target. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your startup files such as `.zprofile` is calling `grep foo *` or similar. You need to find and remove that line or change it to `grep -d` is it's useful. See section 2.2 in https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html for a list of zsh startup files to look in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I checked my `.zshrc`, and it seems that the `nvm` path like `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` is caused the `grep...` logs to appear.  I fixed this path, the logs disappeared!!

Answer (score 0):

Linux man pages mention that there is a `-d` option along with which some action can be specified like skip, etc.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html

> -d ACTION, --directories=ACTION

> If an input file is a directory, use ACTION to process it. By default, ACTION is read, i.e., read directories just as if they were ordinary files.  If ACTION is skip, silently skip directories.  If ACTION is recurse, read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  This is equivalent to the -r option.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` command is designed to inspect matching in text files.

If you include directories in `grep` command file list, you get these errors.

If you wan to omit directories from `grep` text files use the following option: `--directories=skip`

If you wan to recurse directories from `grep` text files use the following option: `--directories=recurse`

As stated in the `grep` command help.

```
  -d, --directories=ACTION  how to handle directories;
                            ACTION is 'read', 'recurse', or 'skip'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see that `-d` option can be used to omit directories from the `grep` search.